Reactivate monitor without keyboard / mouse
My setup:
Raspberry Pi 5 with Ubuntu 24.04 installed
Monitor: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_(H)_(with_case)#Working_with_Raspberry_Pi
I changed the /boot/config.txt according to the setup in the wiki, and when booting the system, I get a desktop on the screen once the boot is done. If I do input nothing, it will turn off after some time, which is expected behaviour, but I cannot wake it up again.
A python script is running, doing some monitoring, and I want to be able to wake up the monitor when a certain condition is triggered. I found this: https://askubuntu.com/a/116806
xset seems install, but it does not find any monitor I think?
Output of xrandr:
xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 0 x 0, current 5120 x 1440, maximum 32768 x 32768
default connected primary 5120x1440+0+0 (0x3f) normal (normal) 1354mm x 380mm
        Identifier: 0x3e
        Timestamp:  9989062
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
        Brightness: 1.0
        Clones:
        CRTC:       0
        CRTCs:      0
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter:
        non-desktop: 0
                supported: 0, 1
  5120x1440 (0x3f)  0.000MHz *current
        h: width  5120 start    0 end    0 total 5120 skew    0 clock   0.00KHz
        v: height 1440 start    0 end    0 total 1440           clock   0.00Hz

but the monitor I have attached is 1024x600? And it does not react to xset at all. What am I missing here?
Edit: if I attach a mouse to the raspberry, that wakes the display, so its still attached and configured, just cannot see it from cli

I'm not sure how functional xrandr is under wayland, but you should check if the latter is being used instead instead of X11, a quick search implied to me it is the default on 24.04 if you are using GNOME.

Programs that use X library functions find the X server to communicate with using the DISPLAY environment variable (unless a command line parameter equivalent is used). So to call xset from your event this needs to be set.
I have a Pi setup as a kiosk display that turns off out-of-hours and back on via a cron task. As I used a lightdm session I also have to deal with xauth cookies and so have to be able to read the current cookie value and merge into the current session. As the cron task is being run by root this is not a problem but needs the xauth merge step.
So in the cron script I need to do the following to turn the screen on and avoid it blanking from power saving or the screen-saver timeout.
DISPLAY=:0.0; export DISPLAY
COOKIE=/var/run/lightdm/root/\:0
[ -r $COOKIE ] && xauth merge $COOKIE
xset dpms force on
xset s reset
xset -dpms

For turning it off I just call xset dpms force off once the environment is set up.
DISPLAY=:0.0 is the default for the first display on a system.
